# Codeigniter + doctrine weird behavior with onetomany objects

Tags: codeigniter, doctrine-orm

I'm just started with Doctrine with Codeigniter.

I've got a entity called Material with a relatioship onetomany with another entity called elementCombination.

To retrieve all materials I use this code

```
$query = $this->doctrine->em->getRepository('Entities\Material')->createQueryBuilder('m');
$materials = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

When I lookup the elements (ElementCombination entity) of each material using the getCombination() function I always get the same result for all "material", actually it looks like to merge results as one material could have more elements than others. It's weird, for me.

I "fixed" this by doing this , requerying or refreshing the combination of each material:

```
    foreach ($materials as $key => $material)
    {
        $this->doctrine->em->flush();
        $this->doctrine->em->clear();

                    //$m_combination_1 is a ArrayCollection of ElementCombination

        $m_combination_1= $this->doctrine->em->getRepository('Entities\ElementCombination')->findBy(array('material' => $material->getId()));
        $material->setCombination($m_combination_1);
    }
```

I see this is not a good way to do it, so, I'd like to know if is this behavior normal?, What am I doing wrong?

The yml entities are like this.

Material

```
Entities\Material:
  type: entity
  table: materials
oneToMany:
  similars:
    targetEntity: Similar
    mappedBy: parent
 combination:
    targetEntity: ElementCombination
    mappedBy: material
 .....

 fields:
   id:
     type: integer
     id: true
     generator:
       strategy: AUTO
.....
```

And ElementCombination

```
Entities\ElementCombination:
  type: entity
  table: element_combinations
  manyToOne:
    material:
      targetEntity: Material
      inversedBy: combination
  fields:
    symbol:
      type: string
      length: 3
      nullable: false
      id: true
    maxValue:
      type: decimal
      precision: 6
      nullable: false
      column: max_value
    minValue:
      type: decimal
      precision: 6
      nullable: false
      column: min_value
    avgValue:
      type: decimal
      precision: 6
      nullable: false
      column: avg_value
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I've found the solution (I tnink) the schema is wrong, I've changed to this, and I could get rid off lots of stuff in the code

```
Entities\Material:
  type: entity
  table: materials
  oneToMany:
  similars:
    targetEntity: Similar
    mappedBy: parent
  manyToMany:
   combination:
   targetEntity: ElementCombination
   inversedBy: materials
   cascade: {"remove" , "persist"}
   joinTable:
     name: material_element_combinations
     joinColumns:
       material_id:
         referencedColumnName: id
     inverseJoinColumns:
      element_combination_id:
        referencedColumnName : id
uniqueConstraints:
material_index:
  columns:
    - reference
    - inner_name
```

and for the elementcombination

```
Entities\ElementCombination:
  type: entity
  table: element_combinations
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
    symbol:
      type: string
      length: 3
      nullable: false
    maxValue:
      type: decimal
      precision: 6
      nullable: false
      column: max_value
    minValue:
      type: decimal
      precision: 6
      nullable: false
      column: min_value
    avgValue:
      type: decimal
      precision: 6
      nullable: false
      column: avg_value
```

Regards